# Qt QFileInfo.isDir() returns wrong result

Tags: c++, qt4.8

I have problem with Qt class QFileInfo here is some sample of code

```
 QString path = "C:\\Some\\Path";
 QFileInfo pathFileInfo(path);
 if (pathFileInfo.isDir()){
     qDebug() << "path is dir, cdUp";
     pathDir.cdUp();
  } else {
      qDebug() << "path is not dir, getting dir";
      pathDir = pathFileInfo.dir();
  }
```

When the dir Path exists in Folder "Some" pathFileInfo.isDir() returns false
If i correct path and add a QDir::separator() to it pathFileInfo.isDir() returns true
How to use this methods correctly to detect if the given path is Folder or File?

Comment: What does it do if you change path to
'QString path = "C:\\Some\\Path";'

Comment: it is just a typo in example. Path is with correct escaping and not hardcoded

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with backslashs, they have to be escaped. Replace path declaration by:

```
QString path = "C:\\Some\\Path";
```

or use:

```
QString path = "C:/Some/Path";
```

Hope this fixes your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The Slashes like **"/"** and **"\"** are different in Linux and Windows. You can use the **static** method `QString QDir::toNativeSeparators ( const QString & pathName )` to get the correct path with correct seperators for your platform.

So just do that :

```
QString path = QDir::toNativeSeperators( "/your/path/here" );
//you can also use path2 instead of path since they are both the same
QString path2 = QDir::toNativeSeperators( "/your\path/here" );
 QFileInfo pathFileInfo(path);
 if (pathFileInfo.isDir()){
     qDebug() << "path is dir, cdUp";
     pathDir.cdUp();
  } else {
      qDebug() << "path is not dir, getting dir";
      pathDir = pathFileInfo.dir();
  }
```

[Here is a link to the documentation.](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.6/qdir.html#toNativeSeparators)